# Running integration test in Gradle using junit

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit, integration-testing

I am using Gradle to run my integration test. I am using JUnit for tests. Integration tests are not being executed when a Gradle task is being triggered.
I am using JUnit version 4.12 and Gradle version 3.5.

I am migrating a project from Ant build to Gradle. it executes all the integration tests when ant task is being triggered. I need to replace the build.xml file by build.gradle to execute all the integration test. This is the code in build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testRuntimeOnly 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compileClasspath  sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    runtimeClasspath  sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
}
task run(type: Test) {
    useJUnit()
}
```

I am using another build.gradle file to copy the resources and code dependency to `build/classes` folder. code for this is:

```
distributions {
    distZip.enabled = false
    main {
        baseName = 'project name'
        version = ''
        contents {
            from { 'build.gradle' }
            from { '../config/gradle/common-build.gradle' }
            from {'../gradle*'}
            from { 'build/libs/*.jar' }
            into('build/classes') {
                from('build/classes')
            }
            into('build/resources') {
                from('build/resources')
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

i am using apply to import one build.gradle file into another using this code:

```
apply from: 'buildFileLocation/build.gradle'
```

But whenever I execute the task I am getting this as output:

```
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :run NO-SOURCE
```

Comment: Where do your main Java source files, your unit test source files (if any), your integration test source files, etc. reside in the project directory? Do you use the conventional `src/main/java`, `src/test/java`, etc. or some other directory structure?

Comment: This subproject is for only the integration test. The directory structure is src/main/java for test cases and src/test/resources for resources.

Comment: @Chriki does Gradle 3.5 provides JUnit?

Comment: Yes, JUnit is even the default testing framework. But are you sure that your JUnit-based test classes are under `src/main/java` and that your build setup is exactly as described? If so, you should actually get a build failure since you don’t have JUnit on the compile classpath for that source set …

Comment: @Chriki dependencies contains these classpaths also

        compileClasspath  sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        runtimeClasspath  sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output

but tests are not running.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly … Could you please edit the build script in your question to match exactly the situation in which you get your described build output? Otherwise it's hard to reproduce what's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, it’s still not easily possible to reproduce your setup which appears to be rather special. Hence, a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best.